# sortedBy() selector not sorting List

Tags: kotlin

I have a `sortedBy{}` statement which intends to sort a `List` by the length of the `String` elements:

```
var animals: List<String> = listOf("tiger", "cat", "dragon", "elephant")
fun strLength(it: String) = it.length
animals.sortedBy { strLength(it) }
animals.forEach {println(it)}
```

However it only prints the initial order. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

You have to assign the output of `sortedBy`.

```
  animals = animals.sortedBy { strLength(it) }
```

Because, like many other functions in Kotlin, `sortedBy` doesn’t mutate the input & honour immutability. So it returns a new collection. So it mitigates side-effects. Kotlin encourages this immutable approach. However, there are mutable counterparts of these collections if required.

Comment: Thanks. How can you tell if a function doesn't mutate the input?

Comment: For example, `animals.sortedDescending()` will mutate the collection (i dont have to write `animals = animals.sortedDescending()`)

Comment: There's a naming convention: `collection.sort()` sorts the collection in-place and returns `Unit`, while `collection.sorted()` returns a sorted copy. It's `sort` vs. `sorted`. But the stronger indicator is the return type. If it's `Unit`, it can only do something in-place, otherwise it probably returns a copy.

Comment: And if all else fails, you can always read the documentation... (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html)

Answer (score 3):

`sortedBy` does not sort the list, instead it returns a new list which has the elements sorted. If you don't want a new list, simply use `sortBy`.

Comment: Your list has to be mutable. Use `mutableListOf` instead of `listOf`.